# Wasn't Skynet worried about temporal paradoxes?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

Was Skynet aware, at least in the first *Terminator* film, that it would create a future where Skynet would be created, via the chip in the Terminator?

Alternatively, wasn't Skynet worried about temporal paradoxes?

Comment: Skynet wants to avoid big paradoxes (like invalidating it's own existence) but cares little for small paradoxes

Comment: Also, in the first film it looks like a time loop is happening

Comment: Skynet got an F on Temporal Mechanics 101, taught by Admiral Janeway.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum And, finding ratemyprofessor.com an inadequate vehicle for dispensing his misplaced rage, initiated a nuclear war just to get rid of her.

Comment: IIRC Skynet was losing, or had effectively lost, the war with John Connor by the time of the events of the first Terminator movie. It didn't have anything to lose re: paradox issues.

Answer (score 1):

Skynet's endgoal is to generate a world in which Skynet and things made by Skynet are the only sentients (egoism) and in which the humans are all dead (malevolence). **It's not scared of a paradox as long as it creates a timeline in which Skynet *or a Skynet variant* is in absolute charge.**

- **Egoism**

  > Before long, the machines Skynet had built to be its eyes, ears, and weapons would spread out across the earth to claim its prize. **It wanted a world populated only with endless mechanical refractions of itself, the ultimate egoist, with direct control linkages to automated factories to realize its scheme.** That was the future Kyle Reese had told her about. And the Terminator’s arrival had convinced her of.
  >
  > <sub><sup>T2: Official Novelisation</sup></sub>
- **Malevolence**

  > “Defense Network computer. New. Powerful. Hooked into everything—missiles, defense industry, weapons de sign, the works—trusted to run it all. They say it got smart; a new order of intelligence. **Then it saw all people as a threat, not just the ones on the other side. Decided our fate in a microsecond. Extermination.**” Reese paused again. He glanced back over at Sarah.
  >
  > <sub><sup>Terminator: Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

Comment: I'd love to see a movie where Skynet "wins" --- accidentally creating an alternate universe where Skynet is benevolent to humans, or even subservient. I love the idea of evil so absolute that it destroys itself.